# How to sort items in listbox time wise

Tags: vb.net, forms, sorting, quicksort

I've been trying to sort a list in a listbox via visual basic.net form during runtime in a way that, what i type will stay on the first line pushing previously typed one to preceding line. Such that the first input becomes the last and vice versa.
Any help here will be greatly appreciated

The ascending n descending including the **.sorted** method obviously works differently

Comment: [ListBox.ObjectCollection.Insert(Int32, Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert)

Comment: You're not really sorting the list, because it's not an aspect of the items themselves that determines the order. You're really just saying that you want to add a new item at the top of the list instead of the bottom. As has been implied above, that just means calling `Insert` with an appropriate index rather than calling `Add`.

Comment: Sure thing, thanks a lot man. Got evrytin goin. Newbie got alot to learn haha